# The function sometime wont loop but will save the record, sometime it loop but didn't record

Tags: c

I am creating a module for club management system, but the function won't loop and save records. Sometimes it will loop but didn't save any record, sometimes won't loop but save the record. Can anyone fix my code?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
```

// Structure of the employee

```
struct staff
{
    char name[40];
    int id[7];
    int age[3];
    char position[20];
};

struct staff s;

// size of the structure
long int recsize = sizeof(s);

FILE* fp, * ft;


void addrecord();
void deleterecord();
void displayrecord();
void modifyrecord();
void searchrecord();
void staffmenu();

char another;
```

//main menu

```
int menu()
{
    int funsType;

    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen("staff.dat", "wb+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("\nCannot open file...");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    printf("1) Staff Information\n");
    printf("2) Facility Information\n");
    printf("3) Member Information\n");
    printf("4) Booking Information\n");
    printf("5) Facility Usage Information\n");

    printf("Enter your requirement: ");
    scanf("%d", &funsType);
    switch (funsType) {
    case 1: staffmenu(); break;
    case 2: printf("2"); break;
    case 3: printf("3"); break;
    case 4: printf("4"); break;
    case 5: printf("5"); break;
    default: printf("Please choose the correct number");
        getch();
        menu();
    }
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    menu();
    staffmenu();
}
```

//show staff menu

```
void staffmenu() {
    system("cls");
    int choice;
    printf("\n1. ADD RECORD\n");

    printf("\n2. DELETE RECORD\n");

    printf("\n3. DISPLAY RECORDS\n");

    printf("\n4. MODIFY RECORD\n");

    printf("\n5. SEARCH RECORD\n");

    printf("\n6. EXIT\n");

    printf("\nENTER YOUR CHOICE...\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choice);


    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        addrecord();
        break;
    case 2:
        deleterecord();
        break;
    case 3:
        displayrecord();
        break;
    case 4:
        modifyrecord();
        break;
    case 5:
        searchrecord();
        break;
    case 6:
        fclose(fp);
        exit(0);
        break;

    default:
        printf("\nINVALID CHOICE...\n");
        getch();
        staffmenu();
    }
}

//add record to binary file

void addrecord()
{
    system("cls");
    
    another = 'y';
    
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    while (another == 'y') {
        printf("\nEnter ID : ");
        scanf("%s", &s.id);

        printf("\nEnter Name : ");
        scanf("%s", s.name);

        printf("\nEnter Age : ");
        scanf("%s", &s.age);

        printf("\nEnter Position : ");
        scanf("%s", s.position);

        fwrite(&s, recsize, 1, fp);

        printf("\nWant to add another record (Y/N) : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &another); //When I click n i will back to addrecord but the record didnt't save //It will loop but didn't save the record
        another = getche();//read from keyboard
    }
                 
    
}
```

//delete record from binary file

```
void deleterecord()
{
    system("cls");
    char empname[50];
    char another = 'y';

    while (another == 'y') {
        printf("Enter employee name to delete : ");
        scanf("%s", empname);

        ft = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");
        rewind(fp);

        while (fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1) {
            if (strcmp(s.name, empname) != 0)
                fwrite(&s, recsize, 1, ft);
        }

        fclose(fp);
        fclose(ft);
        remove("staff.dat");
        rename("temp.dat", "staff.dat");
        fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");

        printf("\nWant to delete another record (Y/N) :");
        fflush(stdin);

        another = getche(); // when I click n it will straight close the program but still no delete the record //It wont loop and save the record
    }
}

//display all record from file

void displayrecord()
{
    system("cls");
    fp = fopen("staff.dat", "rb+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen("staff.dat", "wb+");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("\nCannot open file...");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    rewind(fp);

    printf("\n==========================================================");
    printf("\nID\t\tNAME\t\tAGE\t\t\tPOSITION\n",s.id, s.name, s.age, s.position);
    printf("==========================================================\n");

    while (fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1)
        printf("\n%s\t\t%s\t\t%s\t%s",s.id, s.name, s.age, s.position);

    printf("\n\n\n\t");
    printf("Press any key to back to menu......");
    if (getch())
        staffmenu();
}
```

//edit record from binary file

```
void modifyrecord()
{
    system("cls");
    char empname[50];
    char another = 'y';
    while (another == 'y') {
        printf("\nEnter employee name to modify : ");
        scanf("%s", empname);

        rewind(fp);

        while (fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1) {

            if (strcmp(s.name, empname) == 0) {
                printf("\nEnter new id:");
                scanf("%s", &s.id);
                printf("\nEnter new name :");
                scanf("%s", s.name);
                printf("\nEnter age :");
                scanf("%s", &s.age);
                printf("\nEnter new position :");
                scanf("%s", &s.position);

                fseek(fp, -recsize, SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(&s, recsize, 1, fp);
                break;
            }
        }
// Ask for modifying another record

        printf("\nWant to modify another"
            " record (Y/N) :");
        fflush(stdin);
        another = getche();
        
    }
}
```

//search record from binary file

// it can't continue search, it will trigger breakpoint

```
void searchrecord() {
    system("cls");
    int found = 0;
    char namesearch[40];
    char another = 'y';
    while (another == 'y') {
        printf("\n Enter Name to search : ");
        scanf("%s", &namesearch);
        if (fp == NULL) {
            fp = fopen("staff.dat", "wb+");
            if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("\nCannot open file...");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        rewind(fp);
        while ((fread(&s, recsize, 1, fp) == 1))
        {
            if (strcmp(s.name, namesearch) == 0)
            {
                found = 1;
                printf("\nRecord of Staff / Member of %s is\n", namesearch);
                printf("===================================");
                printf("\nID : %s", s.id);
                printf("\nName : %s", s.name);
                printf("\nAge : %s", s.age);
                printf("\nPosition : %s", s.position);
            }

        }
        if (found == 0)
            printf("\nRecord Not Found\n");
        fclose(fp);
        printf("\nSearch another record(y/n) :");
        fflush(stdin);
        another = getche();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  More importantly, please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  The process of minimizing the code will also teach you about using version control (you are using version control, aren't you) and also about debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think the problem is that '\n' from the previous input is in the input stream. My solution would be not to read a char but a string.

```
// Structure of the employee
char another;   ->   char another[2];

//show staff menu
//void addrecord()
another = 'y';  ->   sprintf(another, "y");

while (another == 'y')  ->   while (strcmp(another, "y") == 0)

scanf("%c", &another); another = getche();  -> scanf_s("%s", &another, (unsigned)sizeof(another));
```

these are only a few changes for void addrecord().
I think you would need to change everything with "another".

Comment: yes it worked but the loop for 'n' choice only loop once, if I try to choose 'n' again the program will close.

Comment: and for my void searchrecord it will trigger breakpoint when I try to choose 'y' or 'n' for the loop. I can't find what's the problem is.

Comment: //void searchrecord() printf("\nID : %s", s.id); -> printf("\nID : %d", s.id); printf("\nAge : %s", s.age); -> printf("\nAge : %d", s.age);   you have an integer in your struckt defined but you try to write an string. //struct staff
{
    char name[40];
    int id[7];  -> int id;
    int age[3];  -> int age;
    char position[20];
};   I don't think you really want an array of int here.

Comment: You should delete in your int main() staffmenu(); it just confuses if you try to debug (did the loop work or was it staffmenu()?)

Comment: I using %s because when i use %d for id and age it will show random things or straight skip them. So i use %s for them

Comment: %s is looking for "\0" to determinen the end of the string but if you save it as an int from your struckt to the file there is no "\0" terminator i have just seen you also read the input as %s //void addrecord() scanf("%s", &s.id); i would use %d there too.

Comment: then how do I fix it? I try change to %d but the output show random thing

Comment: Now I have already fixed all problems. Just left a problem is how do I link with header file. Because my file pointer are inside the int main().

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: i put file pointer (eg. fp = fopen("staff.dat", "wb+") in the main function. But i need link this module with the header file . So how did i put the file pointer in it.

Comment: I think you mean something like this.: //yourheader.h extern FILE* fp;   //source.c #inculde "yourheader.h"... int main(){  fp = fopen... }

Comment: did this have a complete guide?